# MYSQL tunnel through SSH on Node JS does not return any results

Tags: node.js, ssh, mysql2, tunnel, ssh2

I am trying to tunnel mysql queries to a remote server. I am using SSH2 and MYSQL2 packages on Node.JS. I tried to adapt the sample code mentioned in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606374/node-js-ssh2-tunnel-keep-alive-and-execute-mysql-queries/65400192#65400192). Here is my code

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const sshClient = new Client();
require('dotenv').config();

var ssh = new Client();
ssh.on('ready', function() {
  ssh.forwardOut(
    '127.0.0.1', 3308, '127.0.0.1', 3308,
    function (err, stream) {
      if (err) throw err;
      const dbServer = {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: process.env.DB_PORT,
        user: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
        ssl: {
            ca: require('fs').readFileSync('./certs/ca.pem'),
            key: require('fs').readFileSync('./certs/client-key.pem'),
            cert: require('fs').readFileSync('./certs/client-cert.pem')
        },
        stream: stream
    }
      var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbServer);
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users` ;',
      function(err, results, fields) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(results); // results contains rows returned by server
      });
    });
}).connect({
    host: process.env.DB_SSH_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_SSH_PORT,
    username: process.env.DB_SSH_USER,
    privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync(process.env.DB_SSH_KEY)
  });
```

Code compiles fine but does not return any results. I am able to connect to the same server with same certificates when I use MYSQL workbench. Any ideas what am I missing?

Comment: Any errors being logged?

Comment: @EricJ. No errors thrown